# Reverse Proxy from nginx won't run. Sites are normal

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

There's some problem with my nginx. At first, starting is OK, surfing through the proxy is fast enough. But after a while, 5 -> 10 visit later, the proxy become slower and slower. Until it stop working. Even if i try to stop the nginx using "-s stop", double check if there are any nginx.exe running, and restart nginx. It's still not working.

Nginx.exe is still running.
Port is still in used.

I am running on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Sp2 IIS6

This is the error i read from the log.

```
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1688#3548: posted events 00000000
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1688#3548: worker cycle
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1688#3548: accept mutex lock failed: 0
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1688#3548: select timer: 500
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: select ready 0
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: timer delta: 500
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: posted events 00000000
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: worker cycle
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: accept mutex locked
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: select event: fd:176 wr:0
2010/08/20 21:14:37 [debug] 1580#5516: select timer: 500
2010/08/20 21:14:38 [debug] 1688#3548: select ready 0
2010/08/20 21:14:38 [debug] 1688#3548: timer delta: 500
2010/08/20 21:14:38 [debug] 1688#3548: posted events 00000000
2010/08/20 21:14:38 [debug] 1688#3548: worker cycle
2010/08/20 21:14:38 [debug] 1688#3548: accept mutex lock failed: 0
2010/08/20 21:14:38 [debug] 1688#3548: select timer: 500
```

And this is the config file i wrote:

```
#user  deploy;
worker_processes  2;
error_log   /app/nginx/logs/error.log debug;

events {
  worker_connections  64;
}

http {
  include        mime.types;
  default_type   application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  tcp_nodelay        on;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_min_length  1100;
  gzip_buffers     4 8k;
  gzip_types       text/plain;

  upstream mongrel {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
        server 127.0.0.1:5002;
        #server 127.0.0.1:5003;
        #server 127.0.0.1:5004;
        #server 127.0.0.1:5005;
        #server 127.0.0.1:5006;
  }

  server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  site.com;
    root         C:/app/sub/public;
    index        index.html index.htm;

    try_files  $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @mongrel;

    location @mongrel {
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
      proxy_redirect    off;
      proxy_pass        http://mongrel;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  }
}
```